# How to create an organic group in ERPAL?

Tags: organic-groups

I find organic group it a good solution but i'm a little lost because i'm just a beginner who try to discover ERPAL and Drupal in base.

I like the organic group module and it's like you said is the best add for ERPAL.
I'm using this article to follow the installa of groups but i did not find how to add this block and where. 
https://www.drupal.org/node/861436.
 in the step 2, i find that erpal has a pregonfigured blocks, so how to activate my group that i've add it in the first step so i can add it from the erpal dashboard by the "add a block button".

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you using ERPAL for Service Providers or ERPAL Platform?

Comment: I'm using ERPAL Platform